# Re-initialize a class instance without creating a new instance?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering if there is a standard way to re-initialize, or re-construct a class instance without creating a new instance all together.

Let's say I have a TestClass instance:

```
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.x=0;
    this.y=50;
    this.z=200;
  }
}

var testClassInstance=new TestClass();
```

And basically, overtime I tweak some of it's values.

```
testClassInstance.x+=250;
testClassInstance.y-=20;
```

Then later on I want to reset all of its values to whatever was defined when the instance was created. I'm wondering if there is a way to then basically reinitialize it, without creating an entirely new instance?

Is something like

`testClassInstance.constructor()`

safe and reliable?

Comment: you could add a function to the class that resets the values and call this instead of constructor()

Comment: Why don't you just create another method, let's say reset(), that restores whatever the initial values were.

Comment: There's a nice answer already, so I won't get in the way. I am curious, though, why do you need this functionality?

Comment: Your question is totally unclear, you're talking about class, but you want to reset objects.

Comment: @Zlatko I should've been more specific. I'm realizing this isn't the actual info I need, but regardless, still useful answers.
I'm working with the THREEjs orbit controls, and I need to enable/disable them. But looking at it now, this question isn't relevent to it's syntax.

Comment: That's why I am asking, because you might actually be better by something else :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.reset();
  }

  reset(){
    this.x=0;
    this.y=50;
    this.z=200;
  }
}

const myTestClass = new TestClass();
myTestClass.x = 5;
console.log(myTestClass.x); // 5
myTestClass.reset();
console.log(myTestClass.x); // 0
```

Answer (score 2):

## This answer was generated because of the first version of this question.

Your class is never modified.  The class is an implementation, what you modify are the instances created using that implementation.

**Look this code snippet:**

```js
class TestClass {
  constructor() {
    this.x=0;
    this.y=50;
    this.z=200;
  }
}

var testClassInstance=new TestClass();

testClassInstance.x+=250;
testClassInstance.y-=20;

console.log(testClassInstance.x);
console.log(testClassInstance.y);

var anotherTestClassInstance=new TestClass();

console.log(anotherTestClassInstance.x);
console.log(anotherTestClassInstance.y);
```

See? the new object has the initial values declared in TestClass's constructor.